# Average of a set of probabilities and their standard distribution

Tags: probability, average, standard-deviation, means

This might be a very basic question. But I came across a series of studies in which all of them describe the probability of an event happening vs. the probability of that event not happening. Each study has a probability of outcome being a number between $0$ and $1.$ For example, probabilities of events in study $A$ are $0.043,$ Study $B$ $0.214,$ study $C$ $0.00,$ study $D$ $0.105.$

Would it be correct to obtain a mean probability with this formula $(A+B+C+D)/4$  and how could I get a standard deviation from each study and the total?

The only data available on the studies is the number of participants is $N$, events and odds ratio with a $95\%$ CI comparing treatments.

Comment: It sounds like you have p values for various studies as a difference from some control with n as the only other statistic. You can get a Z or t score from that (assuming a difference in means for a normal distribution) but unless you know the difference in means of the data, I don't see how you can get the standard deviation. As for an average probability, having different n values for A, B, C and D can make that complicated. Different n values would weight the individual probabilites differently. What is the relationship between A,B,C and D that makes an average probability appropriate?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply and confusion. when I wrote P I meant it as a probability ex. study A 4.3%, study B 21.4%, study C 0% study D 10%.

Comment: Reading this again, it's isn't totally clear whether this is a binomial distribution like tossing a coin or the result of a t-test for a difference between samples. What does probability of events in study A mean?